# BIOS updates via Ubuntu Software App

Tags: apt, bios

I usually use command line `apt-get` to keep my system updated. In Feb 2018 Dell had a a BIOS update for my laptop and I flashed it manually via USB.

Today I launched the Ubuntu Software App and noticed a BIOS update which it installed smoothly. I just want to know more about how this process works where the App gets the firmware and installs it. My usual `apt-get update`/`upgrade` never showed it. Is it also possible to do this via command line?

Comment: See https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln171755/updating-the-dell-bios-in-linux-and-ubuntu-environments?lang=en and other brands  are regularly being added using LVFS. https://fwupd.org/vendorlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

1. Gets the list of updates for connected hardware:

`fwupdmgr get-updates`

2. Updates all firmware to latest versions available:

`fwupdmgr update`

---

Noteworthy:

1. Get all devices that support firmware updates:

`fwupdmgr get-devices`

2. Downgrades the firmware on a device:

`fwupdmgr downgrade [DEVICE_ID]`